# Scrapy keeps return empty value

Tags: scrapy

I'm scraping http://www.germandeli.com/Meats/Sausages

I would like to extract the link for every product(or item) from the page. I use scrapy shell to test but it keeps return the empty value [ ].

Here is the code I use:

```
response.xpath('*//h2[@class="item-cell-name"]/a/@href')
```

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When requested by a browser and disabled javascript there is a message that reads `To view this site, you must enable JavaScript or upgrade to a JavaScript-capable browser. `. While `scrapy` does not render `javascript` this might be the reason for your empty result.

Comment: @FrankMartin Thank you for your reply. I think you right. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: One way is to use a (headless) browser: some use Selenium, some others use [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) + [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) plugin: you basically delegate to this external Splash service the task to render the page like a browser would do, and send you back the HTML after rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well unfortunately the item content is rendered through JS. But luckily the URL sends a AJAX request to fetch a JSON of the items. This makes it much easier for us to parse it. You can check the XHR tab in the google chrome console to imitate the request with the required headers.

[This URL](http://www.germandeli.com/api/items?include=facets&fieldset=search&language=en&country=US&currency=USD&pricelevel=5&c=452206&n=2&category=Home%2FMeats%2FSausages&sort=custitem_is_orderable%3Adesc%2Cstoredisplayname%3Aasc&limit=48&offset=0) returns the list of products. The `limit` and the `offset` parameters in the URL can be played around with to fetch the next set of data. Also to parse the JSON content you can use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) from the standard library.